# How to write the docker file when your server.js files resides in a differnet directory

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have a nodejs application and the structure is as below
Dockerfile  README.md   api     artifacts   A23.properties  scripts
inside api directory, i have the server.js file.

```
# Instal  Node as base and then all other packages

FROM node:latest
MAINTAINER test23

# Current Working Directory
WORKDIR /test23/

# Copy Code Contents into primary directory
COPY . /test23/

# Install app dependencies

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install unzip -y

EXPOSE 3306 3000
```

Now I have

```
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

or

```
CMD ["node", "/test23/api/server.js"]
```

or

```
CMD ["node", "/api/server.js"]
```

none of the above combination actually works and it fails to start the node server.

Any leads on how to get this working using the docker file is really helpful.

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Are you getting an error? If so, which one? Do all commands fail with the same behavior? Does anything change between them? You have to be a lot more specific in defining the problem before a solution can be found :)

Comment: Also, where is the location of `server.js`?

Comment: No errors seen on either of the commands. Docker logs is clean, i.e there is no output.

I manually login to the conatiner using docker exec command --> CD to /test23/api/server.js and the run node server.js and it comes up.

Server.js is located the the below directory

/test23/api/server.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** `WORKDIR /test23/` means that it is set as a working directory.

**2.** `COPY . /test23/` copies folder `api` inside `/test23` folder.

So, when we are in `/test23` folder the path to `server.js` file is `api/server.js`.

The final `Dockerfile` is:

```
# Instal  Node as base and then all other packages 
FROM node:latest
MAINTAINER test23

# Current Working Directory
WORKDIR /test23/

# Copy Code Contents into primary directory
COPY . /test23/

# Install app dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install unzip -y

EXPOSE 3306 3000 

CMD ["node", "api/server.js"]
```